# get index from row element in protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I search for a row in a table using Protractor. I want a specific row with a specific ID in one of the columns. With a filter list I am able to read that id but now I want to know to which row index corresponds that id.

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in list)')).count().then(function (count) {
var list = element.all(By.binding('item.ID'));

var ID = list.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === myID;
    });
}
expect(ID.getText()).toBe(myID));
```

The thing is that I want to read the value from another column but from the same element, so for that I would need the index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.each` in order to carry along an element's index with the element.

```
  var theIndex;
  element.all(by.repeater('item in list')).each(function (theElement, index) {
     if( **Test this is the correct item** ){
       theIndex = index;
     }
  });

  browser.driver.sleep(0).then(function () {
    // Use theIndex
  });
```